# C# Event Invoke and synchronization

Tags: c#, winforms, events, synchronization

I got to work on the code of a former colleague and there is a section of code which I don't fully understand, could someone please give me an int about the difference of the two sections of code?

This code will notify of processed Images, that several components will listen and display.

```
public event EventHandler<ImageProcessedEventArgs> ImageProcessed;
```

The code I don't understand / see benefit is the following. Could it be improved / simplified?

```
public void OnImageProcessed(ImageProcessedEventArgs e)
{   
    if (ImageProcessed != null)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref imgProcTickets) == 1)
        {
            var delLst = ImageProcessed.GetInvocationList();
            int numFiredEvt = delLst.Length;

            foreach (var del in delLst)
            {
                (del as EventHandler<ImageProcessedEventArgs>).BeginInvoke(
                    this,
                    e,
                    iar =>
                    {
                        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numFiredEvt) == 0)
                            Interlocked.Decrement(ref imgProcTickets);

                        try
                        {
                            var evtHandler = iar.AsyncState as
                                EventHandler<ImageProcessedEventArgs>;

                            evtHandler.EndInvoke(iar);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    },
                    del
                );
            }
        }
        else
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref imgProcTickets);
    }
}
```

Why couldn't it be something similar to the following.

```
public void OnImageProcessed(ImageProcessedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageProcessed?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

The issue I had is that in the existing code (top one) sometimes `imgProcTickets` becomes higher than 1 and it stops Invoking images.

Comment: The "issue" you describe seems intentional/by-design: it appears to have been deliberately designed so that all event handlers are invoked serially, and to avoid blocking it simply drops subsequent calls to OnImageProcessed if one is already in progress. It would not be a good idea to fundamentally change this design without understanding _why_ this former colleague made this design choice. Hopefully they left some documentation.

Comment: @JeffE thanks, not even comments. But I can access all the code.
From my understanding at first it seemed that it was supposed to ensure that the same ImageProcessedEventArgs goes to all subscribers, is this correct?